# Missing coordinates of a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

We are given points $A(6,2,4)$, $B(7,5,9)$, $C(x,6,13)$ and $D(8,3,z)$. I need to find $x$ and $z4 so $ABCD$ is a parallelogram. I know there has been similar questions but I cant seem to get it to work.
Which properties should I use and how?

Answer (score 2):

Use $$\overrightarrow{AB} = \overrightarrow{DC} \;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\; C-D = B-A$$
so $$ (x,6,13)-(8,3,z) = (7,5,9)-(6,2,4)$$
thus

$$x-8= 7-6 \;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\; x= 9$$
and 
$$ 13-z = 9-4  \;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\; z=8$$

Answer (score 1):

The properties should be quoted is "the diagonals of a //gm bisect each other". Therefore, x and z can be found by equating the midpoints of (A and C) and (B and D).